# mysqldumpslow query time difference

Tags: mysql

I am a new user to mysqldumpslow and I am trying to understand the following:

a) What is the difference between Query time and average query time ?
b) For a query like this :

Count: 12  Time=363.73s (4364s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), ekb[ekb]@localhost
  delete from sys_temp_random

What does this time value represent - (4364s)  ?

Answer (score 0):

That number represents the total time spent on the query.

Comment: what is the difference between Query time and average query time ?

Comment: There actually is very little difference between those 2 numbers, as the Average time is simply multiplied by the count. (12*363=4364)

Answer (score 0):

```
What does this time value represent - (4364s)?
```

Its the total `count` (no of times this query run) multiplied by the average running time then the result get floored =>  `floor (12 * 363.73)  = 4364`